# The css animation property marked invalid in Sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

The css animation property is not working in sharepoint 2010 page when editing using Sharepoint designer in 'advanced mode'. It shows an error saying "The property is marked invalid because it's not supported by current schema".
how can I solve this?

Comment: just ignore it?